# How to remove or disable mobile menu on wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, drop-down-menu, menu

I am using OceanWP theme and I am having trouble removing the main menu on mobile only. Do I need to go into the theme's code or remove it a different way?

Answer (score 1):

Try with below code or Find the class name and use css to with display:none with media query.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  nav{
    display:none;
  }
}
```